# JS -> Accessing a variable from another function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this site and to programming in general and I'm a bit stuck on a school assignment.
For reference here is my code I'm currently working on: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YKWQzLMF)

```
function initChests(){
  let gameChests = document.getElementById('chests');

  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let singleChest = document.createElement('img');
    singleChest.src = 'images/chest-closed.png';
    singleChest.alt = 'A chest'
    singleChest.style.marginRight = '20px';

    gameChests.appendChild(singleChest);
  }
}

function initChestEventListeners() {
  singleChest.addEventListener('click', chestClicked);
}

function chestClicked(e){
  console.log("hello");
}
```

Now to my problem. What I want to do is access the variable `singleChest` in my `initChestEventListeners` function without making the variable global.

I am aware I can just put the `singleChest` addEventListener inside the `initChests` function, but that's not quite what I want to do either. I want to make it work with the function structure I have if possible.

Is this something that is possible and if so, can someone please explain what I would need to do or redirect me to a guide that could help explain the solution?

Thank you in advance!
Kind regards.

Comment: `singleChest` is defined in a loop, which makes three of them. Which one do you want `singleChest` to refer to outside the loop? You could call `initChestEventListeners()` from the loop and pass `singleChest` to it.

Comment: I basically want all three of them to be "clickable" so to say. I think you're on to something here. Thanks a lot for this tip! I will try this.

Comment: Add the event listeners in the loop then.

Comment: @Pointy - Yes, I could do this. But I would like the code to be structured kind of the way I have it. But this is definitely an option. Thank you!

Comment: Well you could also use various completely different approaches, such as creating a *delegating* event handler and some identifying class on your `<img>` elements. However, you said you're a newcomer to web development, and in this case the simplest thing to do is centralize the work you're doing in that main loop.

Comment: Alright. I will do the simpler method for now and start reading up on event delegation then. Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add an event listener to the parent element instead, the `gameChests`, and on click, if the clicked element is an `img`, do something with it:

```js
function initChests() {
  const gameChests = document.getElementById('chests');
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let singleChest = document.createElement('img');
    singleChest.src = 'images/chest-closed.png';
    singleChest.alt = 'A chest'
    singleChest.style.marginRight = '20px';

    gameChests.appendChild(singleChest);
  }
}

function initChestEventListeners() {
  const gameChests = document.getElementById('chests');
  gameChests.addEventListener('click', chestContainerClicked);
}

function chestContainerClicked(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('img')) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("hello", e.target);
}

initChests();
initChestEventListeners();
```

```html
<div id="chests"></div>
```

This method of watching for events that bubble up to the parent element is called event delegation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is definitely a solution. I will read more about event delegation. Thank you.